# ¿Cuáles son las distinciones más importantes del castellano amazónico del Perú?

Tags: diferencias-regionales, español-neutral, perú

Se dice [aquí](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idioma_espa%C3%B1ol_en_el_Per%C3%BA) que hay cinco variaciones del español hablado en el Perú, y que el [español amazónico](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Espa%C3%B1ol_amaz%C3%B3nico) parece predominar en un área geográficamente más extensa que los otros dialectos. Supongo que hay también un idioma común y distintamente peruano, ¿verdad?

Si tal modo de español peruano existe, ¿hay recursos educativos en la red para aprender a usarlo?

Comment: Quizás el sitio donde mejor te puedan responder sea la [Academia Peruana de la Lengua](http://www.academiaperulen.org/contacto) pero imagino que estarán más interesados en preservar que los peruanos se sigan entendiendo entre sí, y con el resto de los hispanohablantes del mundo, que en fomentar el uso de dialectos.

Answer (score 5):

Siguiendo los enlaces de Wikipedia y [yendo a las referencias](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Espa%C3%B1ol_amaz%C3%B3nico#Referencia) encontramos muy poca documentación del español amazónico, aunque bien parecen haber unos pocos estudios.  [*Etnologue*](http://www.ethnologue.com/language/spq) le asigna un código propio al español amazónico y afirma que no es directamente inteligible con el registro normal.

Sobre el español de Iquitos (ciudad peruana en el Amazonas), Wikipedia ofrece otra fuente, esta vez un artículo en un blog [*El castellano de Loreto*](http://escuchalacalle.blogspot.com/2012/04/el-castellano-de-loreto.html) el cual a su vez cita como fuente a *El español amazónico hablado en el Perú* sin vínculos ni especificar si esto es un libro, un trabajo académico o qué tipo de obra.

Los links en Wikipedia en inglés no son más dicientes: agregan un blog que ya no existe y una página en un libro sobre el español hablado que marca apenas una característica del habla de Loreto-Ucayali, no como tratado del español en esa área sino sobre el uso de esa expresión en diferentes dialectos del español.

No hay referencias específicas a las afirmaciones que se hacen en el artículo de Wikipedia lo que me lleva a pensar que es investigación original o, simplemente, mala práctica de redacción.

Dicho esto me atrevería a decir que **no**, no hay recursos en la red para aprender a usarlo.  Sí debe haber recursos que describen, pero posiblemente se encuentran principalmente en las facultades de lingüística de las universidades peruanas, e imagino que son más orientados a **describir** cómo se habla el español en la Amazonía peruana que a *enseñar a usarlo*.

Comment: La fuente que mencionas es *El español amazónico hablado en el Perú: hacia una sistematización de este dialecto* por Luis Hernán Ramírez. Es un libro de 2003.

Answer (score 3):

Perú tiene tres regiones:  costa, sierra, y selva.  Cada región tiene sus localismos, aunque algunos localismos se propagan por todo el país.

La amazonía peruana es de escasa población,a pesar de ocupar un área muy extensa.
La selva no fue conquistada por los incas, y por eso el quechua no se propagó allí como en la sierra.  Eso puede explicar la diferencia entre localismos selváticos y los de la sierra o la costa.

Comment: No entiendo bien la referencia que haces al hecho que los Incas no conquistaron la zona con el avance del idioma español. Podrías, tal vez, elaborar un poco más?

Comment: Por lo contrario, la referencia de Sr Mitty es perfectamente comprensible. Es decir, los Incas habían conquistado sus regiones (menos la selva), y pues los conquistaores hispanohablantes han reémplazado los Incas, por eso el quechua está hablado en la selva más frequentamente que los otras idiomas.

Comment: Yo dije que yo no lo entendía :P No que era incomprensible :P Porque, acaso los españoles no podrían haber conquistado zonas no Incas? Mas alla de la lógica, preguntaba como hecho histórico.

Comment: La amazonía era terreno mucho más difícil de explorar que la sierra o la costa.  Y la población selvática era casi imposible de subyugar.  Por eso la exploración de la selva casi no se realiza hasta el siglo veinte.

Comment: @WalterMitty lo que dices es verdad en las partes más espesas de la selva. Por otro lado dijiste "el español no reemplazó el quechua", lo cual parece inferir que el idioma hablado en la zona era el quechua. Aqui puedes ver http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Quechuan_langs_map.svg que no es el caso, y aquí puedes ver lenguas de la zona http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenguas_amaz%C3%B3nicas Si tu post hubiera dicho que el idioma español no avanzó tanto por la impenetrabilidad de la selva, me parecería bien. Los españoles conquistaron mucho mas que las zonas de habla quechua.

Comment: Mi falta.  Quise decir que cuando el español entró en la selva, el idioma anterior no era el quechua.

Comment: Tengo que desdecirme.  Redacté mi respuesta anterior para que se deje entender mejor.

Answer (score 2):

En [Perú](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peru) el idioma oficial es el [español](http://dle.rae.es/espa%C3%B1ol) o [castellano](http://dle.rae.es/castellano), 
con lo cual si sabes hablar este idioma ya sabes hablar el "idioma peruano."

Ahora bien, en diferentes países de habla castellana vas a encontrar que la gente usa diferentes términos comúnmente, o se expresan ligeramente diferente. Incluso puedes llegar a encontrar que en varios países la misma palabra tiene diferente connotación o significado.

Pero todas estas diferencias, no son lo suficientemente grandes para considerarlas un idioma por derecho propio. Por lo que entiendo se le denomina dialecto.

En muchos casos, sucede que estas variaciones en uso y significado, ni siquiera son válidas en el marco del idioma (oficialmente válidas). Suele pasar que el idioma se deforma en su uso, alguna regla difícil de recordar por lo que la gente la ignora (y tantas otras cosas).

Respecto a tu pregunta, te puedo recomendar diferentes cosas, que van a depender de tu objetivo.

Si quieres hablar como un nativo, vas a necesitar mucha práctica, y comunicarte con nativos. No bastará con leer páginas web y demás.

Si lo que quieres es entender cómo habla la gente comúnmente, bueno por la forma en que escribiste ya vas bien encaminado. Te faltaría entender la jerga de la zona.

También haz de tener en cuenta que sin importar el lugar o el idioma, diferentes grupos de personas hablan diferente. Por ejemplo si piensas en grupos de personas de diferentes edades, te darás cuenta que el uso del idioma puede variar enormemente. Creo que la gente más joven tiende a usar más vocablos tipo "jerga", y la gente mayor tiende a usar el idioma de forma más formal (aunque no siempre es el caso).

Dicho esto, puedes realizar búsquedas en Google para encontrar la jerga de la zona que te interesa, por ejemplo:

- [Peruvian Slang](http://howtoperu.com/2010/11/13/peruvian-slang-words-and-phrases/)
- [Jerga juvenil de Perú](http://www.wikilengua.org/index.php/Jerga_juvenil/Per%C3%BA)
- [Jerga Peruana](http://www.elbuscapersonas.com.pe/jergas/jergasperuanas6.htm)

Respecto a la pronunciación o tonada del lugar, podrías escuchar programas de radio, televisión o incluso webcasts de la zona que te interesa, de esa forma podrías llegar a obtener un mejor entendimiento de la forma en que pronuncian.

De todas formas en un caso tan particular, en el que te interesa la forma en que las personas hablan el idioma en una forma específica, te recomendaría que encuentres gente de la zona con la que comunicarte. Quizás un buen punto de comienzo serían páginas de chat del Perú.

Espero que esto te sirva!